# Is it possible to make websphere MQ work with UDP protocol?

Tags: java, udp, ibm-mq

Well, the title is quite self expleneationry.. I'm tryin to improve mq client connection time since it takes to much time in my app.
([look here for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587226/how-to-improve-mq-client-create-conncetion-time))

Comment: Why don't you put directly your code here?

Comment: @helloflash Because it's not really relevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQ previously had the UDP protocol available on AIX only. It was removed a few releases ago. TCP/IP is the transport of choice now. If you are having long connection times, you should get your network guys involved.

Comment: Since you have intrest in IBM MQ, You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587226/how-to-improve-mq-client-create-conncetion-time) to see how I solved the issue. This solution didn't appear in any of your FAQ.

Comment: I'm glad to see you solved your network issue. MQ is just a standard socket application and is reliant on the network underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ clients connect to queue manager over TCP sockets as TCP is connection oriented and reliable. Messaging applications require this kind of QoS from underlying transport. UDP is not connection oriented and reliable when compared to TCP.

You say your application takes lot of time to connect, have you looked at if there are any issues in your network? Are you connecting over slow network? Is your application the only one that takes time to connect or other applications have similar problem?